# VC++ sending message between two application

Tags: delphi, post, message

I have been searching to send a message from Microsoft Visual C++ to another application created in Delphi for 2 hours.

In delphi I know how to read the data. But I don't know exactly how to send a message in MVC++

I hope you can get me a code.

**So for the next code I want a translation in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010, my project it is a console project.**

```
const 
  MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 4242; 

type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm) 
    Button1: TButton; 

procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 

  end; 
var 
  Form1: TForm1; 
implementation 
{$R *.DFM} 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  txt: string; 
begin 
  txt := 'Hello World'; 
  SendMessage(Form1.Handle, MY_MESSAGE, 0, DWORD(PChar(txt))); 
end; 


end.
```

And with this code I should read the data. Also I want to be compatible.

```
const 
  MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 4242; 

type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm) 

    // Handler that receive the Message 

procedure MessageReceiver(var msg: TMessage); message MY_MESSAGE; 
  end; 
var 
  Form1: TForm1; 
implementation 
{$R *.DFM} 


procedure TForm1.MessageReceiver(var msg: TMessage); 
var 
  txt: PChar; 
begin 
  txt := PChar(msg.lParam); 
  msg.Result := 1; 
  ShowMessage(txt); 
end; 
end.
```

So my application contains two parts: One in Microsoft Visual Studio, i use opencv and i want to send a message to the second application, which is created in Delphi.

Comment: You mean sending a message using SendMessage?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's either one or the other. Since you know how to read in Delphi, can you post that code, so someone know what kind of write counterpart you need? Also, since you need VC++ code, this isn't actually a Delphi question.

Comment: There's no such thing as a Windows pipeline. Do you mean a named pipe?

Comment: You are right I have just rewritten my question.

Comment: You can't use user-defined messages to send pointers across processes. You need to use `WM_COPYDATA`.

Comment: How I use them? I was searching and I don't know how to import that code because it is a simple console project and I need handlers

Comment: Use AllocateHWnd to create a window to receive the WM_COPYDATA message.

Comment: AllocateHWnd is a function from Delphi. I need all these parameters DialogBox( ghInstance, "InfoDlg", hWnd, (DLGPROC) InfoDlgProc );

Comment: OK, then it looks like you have some work to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use the pipeline, but I have used before the following scheme:

Use `WM_COPYDATA` message using `SendMessage()`. Here is a reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx

and the example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009(v=vs.85).aspx

You will need to use `FindWindow` to get a handle to the application you want to send the message to.

Comment: I don't know how to use that code. I am not a programmer in MVC++ Thank you, i rewrote my question, to be simpler for understanding

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WM_GETTEXT` or `WM_COPYDATA` message to send buffers of data back and forth between applications. I once searched for a way to send a buffer like `WM_GETTEXT` does, only with a different message. The original code can be found here:

http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?p=275167#post275167

I don't know if everything still works (haven't used it since), but it did back then.

```
// The order (first Buffer, then BufferLength) seems more sensible, although with
// WM_SETTEXT they are actually the other way around.
function SendTextMessage(Handle: THandle; Msg: Integer; Buffer: Pointer; BufferLength: Integer): Cardinal;
var
  ProcessHandle: THandle;
  ProcessId: Cardinal;
  VirtualBuffer: Pointer;
begin
  // Get the id of process to which the handle belongs.
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(Handle, @ProcessId);
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, ProcessId);

  if ProcessHandle = 0 then
    RaiseLastWin32Error;

  // Allocate a virtual buffer in the process
  VirtualBuffer := VirtualAllocEx(ProcessHandle, nil, BufferLength,
                           MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  if VirtualBuffer = nil then
    RaiseLastWin32Error;

  try
    // Send a message to the handle, passing the virtual pointer as a buffer
    Result := SendMessage(Handle, Msg, BufferLength, Integer(VirtualBuffer));

    // Read the resulting value from the virtual buffer into the given buffer
    if not ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, VirtualBuffer, Buffer, Result, Result) then
      RaiseLastWin32Error;

  finally
    VirtualFreeEx(ProcessHandle, VirtualBuffer, BufferLength, MEM_RELEASE);
  end;

end;
```

And call it like this:

```
var
  h: THandle;
  b: array[0..1024] of Char;
begin
  h := Cardinal(StrToInt(Edit1.Text));
  // Not like this
  //SendMessage(h, WM_GETTEXT, 1024, Integer(@b));

  // But like this
  SendTextMessage(h, WM_USER+1, @b, 1024 * SizeOf(Char));
  ShowMessage(b);
```

Read the message like this:

```
procedure WM_USERPLUS1(var Msg: TWMGetText); message WM_USER+1;


procedure TForm2.WM_USERPLUS1(var Msg: TWMGetText);
begin
  with Msg do
    Result := StrLen(StrLCopy(PChar(Text), PChar('Hallo wereld'), TextMax - 1)) * SizeOf(Char);
end;
```

It's probably just as easy to use `WM_COPYDATA`, though. :D

Comment: Thank you, i rewrote my question, to be simpler for understanding

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this instead of using `WM_COPYDATA` as nature intended?!

Comment: Like I said, it's probably just as easy to use WM_COPYDATA, but on the other hand it's an interesting exercise and it allows you to use whatever message you want. Feel free not to use it. :)